# Code Signing ServiceCertificate

Tags: wcf, certificate, ssl-certificate, wcf-security, wif

At my work we've a custom WIF enabled solution, we aren't using it in production yet but everything seems to be working and the tokens seems to be encrypted. The realms of the Relying Party's are validated but atm the STS doesn't require a Relying Party certificate.

So each customer will have a own STS, a own frontend, a own middle-tier hosting workflows and a own backend with wcf services. The frontend and the middle-tier are (mostly) going to be hosted in the same DMZ, both on internet and the backend will be hosted at the customer on internet ofcourse.

Now what we don't want is to force our customer into buying 3 SSL certificates together with 3 different Code Signing certificates. However we advice the customer to buy a wildcard certificate and use it on the different servers. Now the only problem are the Code Signing certificates.

Do we need the Code Signing certificates? Do we just need one? Or can we use the SSL certificate for it, especially on the backend server?

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <!--Certificate added by FedUtil.  Subject='CN=DefaultApplicationCertificate', Issuer='CN=DefaultApplicationCertificate'.-->
        <serviceCertificate findValue="FC5E167B0EC1835ED453CC25C0A70CEC183BB31A" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```